# Firestore collection query based on document's field of type of an object

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Having the following document's schema is it possible to query a collection of documents based on the object's field (in this case `user.uid`) of a document?

If `uid` would exist outside/aside of `user` field I could simply perform `db.collection("/users").where("uid", "==", userId)` to fetch query-specified documents, but having it within complicates the issue.

```
{
  user: {
    uid: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a **map** field `user` with a nested `uid` fild in there, you an query it with a `.`:

```
db.collection("/users").where("user.uid", "==", userId)
```

Comment: Would it be also possible to query whole user object (which would include comparison of all the nested fields) as `db.collection("/users").where("user", "==", user)` given the `user` object is of type `user` in Firestore database?

Comment: I think that should be possible, as long as you ensure you pass the exact same representation that the database expects (as it compares pretty much a binary comparison between the grpc data in that case).